# R : From any matrix (matA), create a matrix containing the columns of matA having all values smaller than 6

Tags: r, matrix

if

```
matA[4][4]=
15  5   5   0
0   5   6   1
3   0   3   3
4   4   4   2
```

then answer would be

```
answer[4][2]=
5 0
5 1
0 3
4 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider `mat` is your matrix, then:

```
> mat[,apply(mat<6, 2, all)]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    0
[2,]    5    1
[3,]    0    3
[4,]    4    2
```

Answer (score 0):

`Filter()` is a good option if you store your data in a data.frame instead of a matrix:

```
A <- matrix(c(15, 0, 3, 4, 5, 5, 0, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 0, 1, 3, 2), nrow = 4)
d <- data.frame(A)
Filter(function(x) max(x) < 6, d)

  X2 X4
1  5  0
2  5  1
3  0  3
4  4  2
```